# How to detect one column changed with gorm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, go, activerecord, orm, go-gorm

Rails' ActiveRecord has `saved_change_to_attribute` method:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Dirty.html#method-i-saved_change_to_attribute

It can detect which column has been changed then do something.

Didn't find any method with Go's ORM library `gorm`. Is it possible?